# Html code on raise exception

Tags: html, oracle, plsql

Well, I do not have much knowledge about pl/sql nor Oracle and I get an issue that i can't solve.

I want to show an html code or a procedure when I raise an exception manually and I tried it in a million ways and this one is the most "reasonable" solution that I found and it keeps without working.

In this code I'm trying not to let people delete and artist if an album only has this artist and because of this I wanted to show an html page saying that instead of the debug page of oracle.

```
create or replace TRIGGER delete_artist
after delete
ON artist
DECLARE
   albumartist NUMBER;
   user_xcep EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   select count(*) INTO albumartist from
   (
      select a.ID, count(cn.artist)
      from album a left join conjunt cn on a.id = cn.album
      group by a.ID
      having count(cn.artist) = 0
   ) album_artist;
   IF albumartist > 0 THEN
      RAISE user_xcep;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   when user_xcep then
      htp.p('<h1>You can&#39t leave an album without an artist</h1>');
   RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing exactly? Would you like to know if there is a better way to accomplish what you want than what you're currently using?

Comment: I'm facing the problem that I'm getting the debug page instead of the html code shown in the code

Answer (score 0):

The exception gets thrown to the program implementing the delete.  This approach does not have the typical "separation of concerns" that one would like to see in well designed applications [i.e. 1) it's up to the trigger to provide the error message; 2) it's up to the application to render it, that can be html, ... whatever].

Answer (score 0):

RAISE inside EXCEPTION block re-raises the EXCEPTION again, and that would cause the debug page to show up. Removing RAISE in the EXCEPTION block should display the htp.p result.

Comment: It does for a moment but then it makes the delete when I don't want to do it :c